# AES-128-CBC don't work on the same way with LUA, PYTHON and PHP

Tags: php, python, aes, esp8266, nodemcu

I have an **ESP8266** with Nodemcu and an **AM2320** sensor.

I am sending temperature and humidity in JSON format in plain text to my **HTTP** server for collecting datas with **PHP** and SQLITE3.

That's working right.

But I wish to encrypt my datas with **AES-CBC**

I encrypt measures on the ESP8266 with **crypto.encrypt()** function and 'AES-CBC' method like this example:

https://nodemcu-firmware.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/crypto/#cryptoencrypt

I do the same encryption on my PC with **Python 3** .

The resulting string matches with the result on the ESP8266 and LUA 5.1

Next I do the same encryption on my PC but with **PHP 7.1**

Alas, the resulting string don't match with the previous results.
I am using the '**AES-128-CBC**' method on **openssl_encrypt()** function.

I put the script in the  three languages in a gist on Github.com :

https://gist.github.com/bazooka07/bed368d313e218fcba332cb2127c70b1

That's wrong in PHP ?

Can You help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried your code with `aes-256-cbc` instead of `aes-128-cbc` in PHP, and it gives the same output. Changing the PHP encrypt method to `aes-256-cbc` should fix the problem..

Comment: I make the change you suggest and it's running.

Maybe the documentation in Nodemcu is outdated

Many thanks for you help

Comment: you're welcome, i'm glad you got it working. please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I add some fix to my gist for working when the length of the message to encrypt don't mach with a multiple of 16 chars.